# Why clang doesn't find .h file in #include "" in the same directory?

Tags: objective-c

This is my first question on this site, so please be patient with me. I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find any relevant.

I have main.m, Person.h and Person.h files in a current directory. In main.m I include Person.h. Then I try to compile main.m, but it gives an error that Person object was not found.

Here is main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    // Create an instance of Person                                             
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

    [person setWeightInKilos:96];
    [person setHeightInMeters:1.8];

    float bmi = [person bodyMassIndex];
    NSLog(@"person has a BMI of %f", bmi);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
{
  // 2 instance variables                                                       
  float heightInMeters;
  int weightInKilos;
}

// instance methods                                                             
- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h;
- (void)setWeightInKilos:(float)w;

- (float)bodyMassIndex;
@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@implementation Person

- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h
{
  heightInMeters = h;
}

- (void)setWeightInKilos:(float)w
{
  weightInKilos = w;
}

- (float)bodyMassIndex
{
  return weightInKilos / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
}

@end
```

Here is the error I get as I try to compile using 'cc main.m -framework Foundation':

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Person", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main-24c686.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I even tried adding the current directory in PATH, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Found my mistake. I forgot to add "#include "Person.h"" to Person.m. After I compiled with "cc main.m Person.m -framework Foundation", it finally worked. Can anyone tell me why I needed to include Person.m in cc call? Why cc didn't find it automatically since it is mentioned in main.m?

Comment: Person.m is not "mentioned" in main.m, and in fact C does not have a concept of "mentioning" files.

Comment: OK, makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is not about the include file "Person.h". The problem is that the `Person`
*class* it not found by the *linker*.

The reason is that you did not add the "Person.m" file to your command line:

```
  cc main.m Person.m -framework Foundation
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I just found out that I forgot to add "#include "Person.h"" to Person.m. Can you please explain why I need to add Person.m with cc? Shouldn't it find automatically?

Comment: @Yerke: When compiling the class *implementation* in Person.m, the compiler must know the class *interface*, which is in Person.h.

Comment: E: I meant why can't I execute as cc main.m -framework Foundation? main.m already has #include Person.h? So it should know the class interface?

Comment: @Yerke: main.m includes Person.h, which contains the *interface* for the Person class (only declarations). Person.m contains the *implementation* of the class (roughly speaking: the actual code for the class).

Comment: @Yerke Related;  you should **never** `#import` a `.m` file.